# Maps with inverses that preserve dense sets.

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ be topological spaces I want to consider the set of maps $f:\mathcal A\to\mathcal B$ such that if $S\subset \mathcal B$ is dense in $\mathcal B$ then the preimage $\left\{a\in \mathcal A : f(a)\in B\right\}$ is dense in $\mathcal A$.

Is there
a)$\qquad$a name, or
b)$\qquad$a useful classification
of such maps?

Comment: Does "map" include continuity if $f$? There is a variant called [irreducible mapping](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Irreducible_mapping).

Comment: Certainly the class includes all open maps, continuous or not.

Comment: It seems that the maps which you considering are exactly [quasi-open](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404305/maps-with-inverses-that-preserve-dense-sets) maps.